# Increase precision of flexible polyline in HERE Maps routing HTTP request

Tags: here-api

I am using a HERE maps HTTP request in the following format:

[https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin=42.55009,-83.11662&destination=42.55277,-83.11675&transportMode=car&return=polyline&apikey=[api-key]](https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin=42.55009,-83.11662&destination=42.55277,-83.11675&transportMode=car&return=polyline&apikey=%5Bapi-key%5D)

This returns a polyline encoding "BG00hlxCrkhx-E0oBzB82C3DgoBpC". I am able to decode the coordinates using the [Python API](https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline). However, the default precision is only 5 decimal places (~meters resolution) in the decoded list.

Documentation of flexible-polyline mentions possible higher precisions (~microns) defined by the [header-content](https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline#header-content). I would like atleast 6-7 decimal places of resolution for the returned polyline. How can I configure this through the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

In the past the HERE platform data extension had 5 digit after decimal point for coordinates.

Therefore by default is 5 digits. It will be [increased to 7 digits](https://developer.here.com/documentation/here-lanes/dev_guide/topics/hd-map-coordinate-encoding.html).

I created for you [issue report on github](https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline/issues/59)